# passive ftp in java - why is the stream not ready

Tags: java, networking, ftp

yet another java problem ...
got a client which should connect to a server via passive mode.
it seems to work fine, i get the ip adress and the port and the passivesocket says that it's ready.

but the passivesocket.getInputStream isn't ready at all - so i can't read from it and don't get the response to LIST.
can't figure out why, any suggestions?

```
public synchronized void getPasvCon() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        // Commands abholen


        // IP Adresse holen
Thread.sleep(200);
        String pasv = commands.lastElement(); 
        String ipAndPort = pasv.substring(pasv.indexOf("(") + 1,
                pasv.indexOf(")"));

        StringTokenizer getIp = new StringTokenizer(ipAndPort);

        // holt die IP
        String ipNew = "";   // IP für den neuen Socket
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (i < 3) {
                ipNew += (getIp.nextToken(",") + ".");
            } else {
                ipNew += (getIp.nextToken(","));

            }
        }


        Integer portTemp1 = new Integer( getIp.nextToken(","));
        Integer portTemp2 = new Integer (getIp.nextToken(","));
        portNew = (portTemp1 << 8 )+ portTemp2;

System.out.println(">>>>> " + ipNew + ":" + portNew);       


        try {

            pasvSocket = new Socket(ipNew, portNew);
            System.out.println("Socket verbunden: "+  pasvSocket.isConnected());

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println("Host unbekannt");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            fromPasvServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    pasvSocket.getInputStream()));
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("Streams bereit: " + fromPasvServer.ready() + " | " );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            writePasvCommands = new PrintWriter(pasvSocket.getOutputStream(),
                    true);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   


Thread.sleep(3000);
        Thread pasvKonsole = new Thread(new PasvKonsole(this));

        pasvKonsole.start();

    }

    public void LIST() throws IOException  {
    writeCommands.print("LIST\n");
    writeCommands.flush();

    }


    public void run() {
        try {
            connect();

    //      getStatus();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            USER();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        PASS();


        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            PASV();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


import java.io.IOException;


public class PasvKonsole extends Thread {
    Client client;
    public PasvKonsole(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("========= PasvKonsole started");

    while(true) {

        try {

            String lineP = client.fromPasvServer.readLine();
                System.out.println("***" + lineP);
                System.out.println("Ich bin da und tue auch was");  
        } catch (IOException e) {}

    }       
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not really understand the code. What is `Thread pasvKonsole = new Thread(new PasvKonsole(this));` good for? Did you try it in a 'non multi-threaded' world?

Comment: whoops, this should be commented out. this thread should print the recieved answers from the server.

Comment: You do never call `LIST` in `getPasvCon`?

Comment: lol, you're right. but now when i do this i get just a bunch of "Null"

Comment: pls make sure to close the question and/or post your answer...

Comment: can't find an option to clsoe this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a `Thread.Sleep` and it works.

Comment: This is **not** the correct way to do this! You should **almost never** call `ready()` and rely on what it returns, it's used *only* for very special cases. *Usually* you'll just want to call `read()` and wait for data to become available. Adding `Thread.sleep` is an ugly, timing-dependent workaround that will break as soon as you run this through a slower network (and needlessly slows down your application if you're running on a faster network). Generally: if you need lots of `Thread.sleep()` in your networking code, then you're doing it wrong!

Comment: @joahim-sauer How do you suggest to wait without thread.sleep? 
"Usually you'll just want to call read() and wait for data to become available. "